# WPF how to set position of progress bar on top of the desktop?

Tags: wpf

thanks for help with previous question! I just got last problem, in my app I only display progress bar and after all open a file. How can I set position of this toolbar? I want it on the top of the desktop when I'm running app. I tried set localization or position on Window settings but I didn't found it.

If you need the code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="80" Width="800" Visibility="Visible"
    ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered" WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Progress" Color="#FF06B025"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <Style x:Key="ProgressBarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Progress}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Animation">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.25"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.25"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.25"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="Animation">
                                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-0.5,0.5"/>
                                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                                            <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1.5,0.5"/>
                                        </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <local:ClippingBorder BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_Indicator" ClipToBounds="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Animation" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20">
                                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                                <SkewTransform/>
                                                <RotateTransform/>
                                                <TranslateTransform/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </local:ClippingBorder>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="TemplateRoot">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Indicator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="pbStatus" Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set [`Topmost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.topmost?view=netframework-4.8) property of the `Window` to `true`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow" ... Topmost="True" ... />
```

Comment: @paprykarz: Did you try this?